# How to set up Media module with image editor?

Tags: 7, media, wysiwyg

I have installed [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) module (7.x-2.0-beta2), but I can't find the module or setting for editing images that is in the video [Drupal 7: Media Upload with Image Editing](https://youtu.be/qmtlW4Xh0ws?t=23).

I want to set up the Media module for editing images as per this video.

Image editor in the media module
[image: Image editor]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the article "[Crop, rotate, and scale embedded images](https://www.drupalgardens.com/documentation/image-editor)".

You have to install [Media crop](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_crop) module. Some details about this module (from its project page):

> Adds cropping, rotating and scaling to the media module's image embed
>   function. Only available for images local to the server (not for
>   remote images), and only when adding media via CKeditor.